# Scraping live stock prices from yahoo Finance and plotting live prices

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi guys I really need some help.
I am trying to plot live stock prices, which are retrieved from yahoo finance using BeautifulSoup in Python.
The webscaping part of the code works because I can see the prices streaming in every second:

```
import lxml as lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np


def real_time_price(stock_code):
    url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code + '&.tsrc=fin-srch')
    r = requests.get(url)
    web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    web_content = web_content.find('div', {"class":'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})
    web_content = web_content.find('span').text
    if web_content ==[]:
        web_content = '99999999999'
    return web_content

HSI = ['AAPL','AMZN','IBM', 'CSCO']

for step in range(1,101):
    price =[]
    col =[]
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
    for stock_code in HSI:
        price.append(real_time_price(stock_code))
    col = [time_stamp]
    col.extend(price)

    df = pd.DataFrame(col)
    df = df.T
    df.to_csv('real time stock data.csv', mode='a', header=False)
    print(col)
```

However, I can't seem to plot the live streaming data:

```
# plotting
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)


def animate(i):

    df = pd.read_csv('real time stock data.csv')
    ys = df.iloc[1:, 2].values
    xs = list(range(1, len(ys) + 1))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
    ax1.set_title('Apple Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[1:, 3].values
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.plot(xs, ys)
    ax2.set_title('Amazon Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[1:, 4].values
    ax3.clear()
    ax3.plot(xs, ys)
    ax3.set_title('IBM Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[1:, 5].values
    ax4.clear()
    ax4.plot(xs, ys)
    ax4.set_title('Cisco Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I tried it in Pycharm and in Jupyter notebook.
I am not sure what to do!

Comment: I think u need to call the animate function every N seconds to redraw the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code still has room for improvement. As part of the process, we will call the function of getting the data to Yahoo Finance in the graph animation function. We'll accumulate the data we get there and draw it.
Since the 'i' in `animate(i)` is a loop count, the data is referenced by the 'i'. Also, `Funcanimation()` specifies the number of frames and no repeat.

```
import lxml as lxml
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import repeat
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np


HSI = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'IBM', 'CSCO']


def real_time_price(stock_code):
    url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code +
           '?p=' + stock_code + '&.tsrc=fin-srch')
    r = requests.get(url)
    web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    web_content = web_content.find(
        'div', {"class": 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})
    web_content = web_content.find('span').text
    if web_content == []:
        web_content = '99999999999'
    return web_content


# style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=1.0, hspace=1.0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date',*HSI])

def animate(i):
    global df
    price = []
    col = []
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
    for stock_code in HSI:
        price.append(real_time_price(stock_code))
    col = [time_stamp]
    col.extend(price)
    df = df.append(pd.Series(col, index=df.columns, name=1), ignore_index=True)

    ys = df.iloc[i:, 1].values
    xs = df.iloc[i:,0].values

    ax1.plot(xs, ys, marker='o', color='r')
    ax1.set_title('Apple Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[i:, 2].values
    ax2.plot(xs, ys, marker='o', color='r')
    ax2.set_title('Amazon Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[i:, 3].values
    ax3.plot(xs, ys, marker='o', color='r')
    ax3.set_title('IBM Stock Price', fontsize=12)

    ys = df.iloc[i:, 4].values
    ax4.plot(xs, ys, marker='o', color='r')
    ax4.set_title('Cisco Stock Price', fontsize=12)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=100, repeat=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]